# How can I edit tracks in Audacity in Sequence instead of in Parallel

Tags: editing

I'm trying to do non-linear editing in Audacity. In other words, I have 8 minutes of audio, and my goal is to cut certain sections, and rearrange them. But, when I cut a track in audacity, and paste it, two tracks now exist, and they play in parallel.....this is obviously not what I want.  Is my question clear?

Comment: When you paste did you confirm that your cursor is located in the original track where you want the clip to be located?

Comment: Hey Ben, I've actually figure out a solution. There is a button named "solo" on each track which helps isolate the sound, and then I use the time shift tool to line up tracks. Not the most intuitive....but it gets the job done.

Comment: Just curious because it seems like there should be a better way - does [this article](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/manual-1.2/tutorial_ed_beginner2.html) describe what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your cursor is on the track where you want to paste the waveform. If you click on the blank area beneath the tracks, a new track will be created, which sounds like what you are doing.